# HTML <select> tag with increase and decrease buttons

Tags: html

I know my question may be silly, but I have really stack here, I have search everywhere and I can't find how to make a simple html  tag to contain increase and decrease buttons at the right! Please help... Thank you for your time!

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: One exclamation point is usually enough.

See: http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-number.php

Comment: Sorry for many exclamation!

Answer (score 3):

This is often how `<input type="number" />` is rendered. There are also many polyfills for browsers that don't natively support it.

Comment: I've only seen native browser implementations of a spinner like this using `<input type="number" />`. The arrows increment or decrement the value of that number. That said, there may be jQuery plugins or other things out there for other field types.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a spinner. An example can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/spinner/

To expand on this, not every browser supports this feature out-of-the-box just yet.

Comment: I have to use jquery for this?

Comment: You can probably come up with some CSS to accomplish it. In the unlikely scenario that you are certain everyone visiting the site is using Chrome, you can just use the <input type="number" /> solution mentioned previously. EDIT: It looks like Android and iOS are supporting it too.